# Cadastro de veículo com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, estou iniciando em php e MySQL.
Estou tentando desenvolver um sistema para o cadastro de um veículo (com foto), e estudando um pouco, me meti na linguagem php em conjunto com o MYSQL.
Acabou que gerei meus scripts, porém não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro e nem salva os dados no meu banco de dados. Alguém pode me ajudar?

**Arquivo index.php**

```
<?php

    include("classe/conexao.php");
    $marca = isset( $_POST ['marca']) ? $_POST['marca']:null;
    $modelo = isset( $_POST ['modelo']) ? $_POST['modelo']:null;
    $ano = isset( $_POST ['ano']) ? $_POST['ano']:null;
    $msg = false;
  if(isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){
    $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4)); //pega a extensao do arquivo
    $novo_nome = md5(time()) . $extensao; //define o nome do arquivo
    $diretorio = "upload/"; //define o diretorio para onde enviaremos o arquivo
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome); //efetua o upload

    $sql_code = "INSERT INTO veiculos (id, marca, modelo, ano, arquivo, data) VALUES(null, '$marca', '$modelo', '$ano', '$novo_nome', NOW())";
    if($mysqli->query($sql_code))
      $msg = "Arquivo enviado com sucesso!";
    else
      $msg = "Falha ao enviar arquivo.";
  }
     ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<title>Cadastro de veículos</title>
<body>
<?php if(isset($msg) && $msg != false) echo "<p> $msg </p>"; ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Marca: <input name="marca" type="text">
        Modelo: <input name="modelo" type="text">
        Ano: <input name="ano" type="text">
        Arquivo: <input type="file" required name="arquivo">
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Arquivo classe/conexao.php**

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $bd = "sitemoraes";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd);
        if($mysqli->connect_errno)
            echo "Falha na conexão: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
?>
```

Print do banco de dados:
[image: Print do banco de dados]

-EDIT-
Após as alterações que o Jackson e o anonimo recomendaram, o script ainda não funciona. Não salva nada no banco de dados e retorna a mensagem de "Falha ao enviar arquivo."

Comment: Olá Guga, primeira coisa, deixa desta forma: `$sql_code = "INSERT INTO veiculos (marca, modelo, ano, arquivo, data) VALUES('$marca', '$modelo', '$ano', '$novo_nome', NOW())";`, como o `ID` é um auto increment, você não deve enviar ele no código.

Comment: Como o campo `id` é uma chave primária ele não pode ser `NULL`. Em seu `INSERT` troque `NULL` por `DEFAULT` ou faça da maneira indicada por Jackson.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda no código.. Fiz do modo do Jackson e do seu, anonimo, porém em ambos os casos agora aparece a mensagem de "Falha ao enviar arquivo." e não envia nada ao banco de dados.

Comment: Guga, dê um `var_dump($_FILES['arquivo'])` e veja se este cara está retornando alguma coisa... Desconfio que o fato de não aparecer mensagem possa ser o fato de ele não estar entrando no `if()`...

Comment: Jacson, o var dump está dando:
  'name' => string 'MoraesAltini.png' (length=16)
  'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp64\tmp\phpEFD.tmp' (length=24)
  'error' => int 0
  'size' => int 607658
  'size' => int 0

Comment: Verifique os valores de `$marca`, `$modelo`, `$ano`, `$novo_nome` antes de inserir no banco de dados. Todas as suas colunas são NOT NULL. Modifique seu programa para utilizar [Declarações preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) pois da forma que está fazendo seu código é suscetível a ataque.